# GAE Authentication and user data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm starting a new project where I need a backend to provide some info to different kind of clients (android and web).
I have been thinking about use Google App Engine because you can generate android client libraries easily.

I don't have any problem in use google authentication but I need to save some custom user info and I need to define custom roles for in-app use. I don't know which would be the correct approach for that.

I have read [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/) but I don't belive they talk about client user authentication, besides if I use any of that services, how could I save my custom data or give them a specific role?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To deal with specifics data on user that are not in standard profile, you need to use persistence and save user info in your model and create some screens for administrator.